# Incorrect sentence in the "Oxford Street" wiki article, isn't it?

Tags: passive-voice

From the "Oxford Street" wiki article:

> The first department stores in Britain opened on Oxford Street in the early 20th century, including Selfridges, John Lewis and HMV.

This is a passive voice sentence, isn't it?

Is it more correct to insert "were"?

> The first department stores in Britain **were** opened on Oxford Street in the early 20th century, including Selfridges, John Lewis and HMV.

If original sentence is correct, then what grammar rule is used here?

Comment: The original sentence is correct; it's not a passive voice sentence.  *Open* can simply mean "to become open or available for business", so "The store opened" is fine.  In fact, making the sentence passive ("were opened") might cause the reader to ask, "OK, but who opened them?"

Comment: *Open* is a 'labile' verb: it is used in both transitive and intransitive senses. For instance, you may say *The bakery is opened at 5 a.m.* or *The bakery opens at 5 a.m.*

Comment: One additional comment for you @chemmalion is that when you make a tag question, after the verb always comes the pronoun that agrees with the main subject in the main sentence. So you should say "This is a passive voice sentence, isn't it?".

Comment: @stangdon That is an answer, and not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence is correct; it's not a passive voice sentence. Open can simply mean "to become open or available for business", so "The store opened" is fine. In fact, making the sentence passive ("were opened") might cause the reader to ask, "OK, but who opened them?" – stangdon

Open is a 'labile' verb: it is used in both transitive and intransitive senses. For instance, you may say The bakery is opened at 5 a.m. or The bakery opens at 5 a.m. – StoneyB

(comments moved to answer under cc licence)

Comment: Smart move. Btw... I can see a difference between **opened** and **were opened**. The former means that they started operating, they started their activity. The latter would mean something like someone made them active.